# Paste as Values

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I really need help pasting the following data set as values.

I am currently wanting to loop through certain Worksheets in my Workbook and copy and paste data from the ones selected.

However, I am unsure as to how to paste the data I am coping as values.

I have written the following code to loop through the worksheets I want and also select the date I want from each worksheet. However, when i paste this data into the Master Data tab, I cannot seem to paste as values.

```
    Sub exa()
Dim wks As Worksheet

For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If Not wks.Name = "Master Data" _
And Not wks.Name = "Query --->" _
And Not wks.Name = "Pivot Portfolio Movement" _
And Not wks.Name = "PortfolioMovement - All" _
And Not wks.Name = "Bank Holidays" _
And Not wks.Name = "Property" _
And Not wks.Name = "Postcodes" _
And Not wks.Name = "Product" _
And Not wks.Name = "PartRedemption" _
And Not wks.Name = "Wrap" _
And Not wks.Name = "Completions Database" _
And Not wks.Name = "Default" _
And Not wks.Name = "ReturningBorrower" _
And Not wks.Name = "Extensions" _
And Not wks.Name = "PortfolioMovement" _
And Not wks.Name = "Drawdowns" _
And Not wks.Name = "Dev Interest WIP" _
And Not wks.Name = "Write Off Loans" _
And Not wks.Name = "Interest Rate" _
And Not wks.Name = "Admin" _
And Not wks.Name = "Datatape --->" _
And Not wks.Name = "Data" _
And Not wks.Name = "Drawn Balance by Loan" _
And Not wks.Name = "Sheet1" Then
wks.Range("H2:N2" & wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row).Copy _
Destination:=Worksheets("Master Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Copy>>Paste is a 2 lines code: `wks.Range("H2:N2" & wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row).Copy`  and `Worksheets("Master Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Answer (score 0):

To paste as values you need to use the  [Range.PasteSpecial method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial): `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Note that if you use an array for the worksheets to skip you can reduce your code like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub exa()
    Dim SkipWorksheets As Variant
    SkipWorksheets = Array("Master Data", "Query --->", "Pivot Portfolio Movement", "PortfolioMovement - All", _
                           "Bank Holidays", "Property", "Postcodes", "Product", "PartRedemption", "Wrap", _
                           "Completions Database", "Default", "ReturningBorrower", "Extensions", _
                           "PortfolioMovement", "Drawdowns", "Dev Interest WIP", "Write Off Loans", _
                           "Interest Rate", "Admin", "Datatape --->", "Data", "Drawn Balance by Loan", "Sheet1")


    Dim Wks As Worksheet
    For Each Wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not (UBound(Filter(SkipWorksheets, Wks.Name)) > -1) Then
            Wks.Range("H2:N2" & Wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
            Worksheets("Master Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next Wks
End Sub
```